# Is there any plugin for sublime text for using library(assets) like we use in dreamweaver?

Tags: dreamweaver, sublimetext3

I have been using sublime for long and loving this because of the reason that it is fast and more efficient with lots of cool plugins available..
But its more time consuming to change the header and footer content in all the pages.
fortunately we have library in Adobe Dreamweaver..
so is there any plugin available in sublime so that we can get the same Dreamweaver like functionality...